# Quartz Job not getting Triggered after Deploying war to glassfish server in maven project

Tags: java, maven, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

Well in `web.xm`l i have added the listener and in its contextInitialized I have written :

```
JobDetail jd = new JobDetail("myjob", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, Myclasstobe triggered.class); CronTrigger tr = new CronTrigger("myCronTrigger", Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP, "0 00 12 ? * MON-FRI"); 
scheduler.scheduleJob(jd, tr);
```

and in `Myclasstobetriggered` I have overridden the execute method where my task is written to be done.

Comment: Maybe this will be help http://quartz-scheduler.org/downloads/catalog

Comment: How is your WAR configured to set up this Job and Trigger? GlassFish doesn't support Quartz out of the box.

Comment: After deploying the war Scheduler context is created (which i can see in logger)but the Override execute method of class which implements the job is not being invoked and my job is inside this method. GlassFish doesn't support Quartz out of the box means I have to use another scheduler for this job to be done or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

GlassFish supports EJB 3.1 which has [`@Schedule`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/Schedule.html). So if you deploy on a Java EE 6 container, I recommend to use the standard tools.

```
@Singleton
public class TimerService {
    @EJB
    HelloService helloService;

    @Schedule(second="*/1", minute="*",hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void doWork(){
        System.out.println("timer: " + helloService.sayHello());
    }
}
```

([copied from Adam Bien](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/simplest_possible_ejb_3_16))

Also take a look at the [Java EE 6 Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html).